# Delete row from tableView if string contains 0

Tags: swift, uitableview

How can I check if a string contains a certain value, and then delete the row accordingly?
For instance: I populate a tableView with concatenated strings containing a `Int` value and a `String` value. An if the strings reads: I have 0 apples, that row should be deleted. But if it says: I have 10 apples, it should be in the tableView.

I concatenate `Int` and `String`values in one View Controller and append it to an array in another View Controller

```
 var amount = Int()
 var text = String()      

 @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        amount += 1
        amountLabel.text = String (amount)

        if let tbc = self.tabBarController as? CustomTabBarController
        {
           tbc.descriptionArray.append("\(counter) \(text))")

        }
     }    



@IBAction func subtractButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if amount != 0
        {
            amount -= 1
        }

        amountLabel.text = String (amount)
        }
    }
```

I want to remove from desriptionArray when the amount is 0. I have tried different versions of `.filter { $0 != valueToCheck }`but cannot make it work.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: "concatenated strings containing a Int value and a String value" Did you concatenated it yourself? If so, why don't you keep the whole model and filter on it instead of filtering on the rendered one?

Comment: I concatenate it myself. The tableView I want to delete from if it contains 0 is in another View Controller. So I concatenate the `Int` and the `String` value and append it to a array in the other View Controller. Updated with code

Comment: Use a struct and keep `String` and `Int` value separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this filter....

```
let rowsToBeDeleted = arrayOfStrings.filter { currentString in
    let splitArray = currentString.components(separatedBy: " ")
    for currentElement in splitArray {
        if Int(currentElement) == 0 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I'm having issues with my system right now, so I was unable to test. I will update the answer if any changes are needed.

EDIT-----

I've tested this and it seem to work as intended. Hope this helps.